# How to show the debug window of Netflix in Firefox (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + D)

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, firefox

I finally had Netflix play at higher resolutions with a native elementary OS browser (specifically Firefox). I am using an updated version of the Netflix 1080p add-on in Firefox and it works flawlessly in my computer ([Netflix 1080p](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/netflix-1080p-firefox/)).

However, I want to see further details of the streaming quality during playback. With Windows (either through their UWP app or browsers), I can easily do this by pressing (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + D) during playback. However, this does not work with any browsers I have in elementary OS. Is there an equivalent combination for Elementary OS for the said shortcut using the Super key?

Comment: There's a way to access the debug menu from the hamburger menu, it's under the web developer. Try as I might, I can't get the proscribed CTRL SHIIFT Z to open it, but it will close it and it is able to be opened with the mouse. Is that the debugger you speak of?

Comment: No that's not it. I was looking for the "Stats for nerds" equivalent for Netflix.

Comment: Ah, in that case I know of no such thing for Elementary. Maybe someone will come along that knows. This SE site is still in beta and doesn't get a lot of traffic, so be patient and someone may come along that knows.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Q is working fine to me. Firefox 83 and Netflix 1080p extension.

Comment: Sadly, even after updating Firefox, the window still wouldn't appear. Both `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + Q` and `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + D` doen't work.